# SAS when obs are zero then quit else continue

Tags: sql, sas

I have very limited programming experience so need a fairly basic answer to this if possible.
I have my first table with call details and then second table with addresses where call id matches 
My problem is when the first table returns zero results (which will happen more often than not) the 2nd table errors as there is no data in the first table. 
so i would like after the first table executes if there is zero results then stop/quit if there are results then continue. I have looked this up but all of the solutions i have found are quite technical and i don't quit understand everything suggested therefor i have been unable to implement. so as already said i really need an explanation that is very simple and easy to understand for 
someone with very basic programming knowledge or suggestions on what else can do to fix this issue. thank you

Comment: In general steps will not stop just because an operation returns 0 observations.  How to do it depends on what steps you are doing. Post an example of the type of steps you are doing so that we can post an answer for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed this with a simple macro:

```
%macro check_data(table=);

data _null_;
    call symput('varnobs',n_obs);
    stop;
    set &table nobs=n_obs;
run;

%if &varnobs = 0 %then %do;
    ENDSAS; 
%end;

%mend check_data;
%check_data("table1");
```

Short explanation, you give the macro the name of your table, it counts the obervations and writes them into macrovariable varnobs. The stop is used because nobs is calculated before executing the set-statement, so i stop the datastep before it. Depending of number in varnobs you can act like you want, like shutting process down with abort or endsas, executing specifc code, etc...

I must admit, using ENDSAS is discussable command, because it shuts down everything, a nicer solution would be to use a logical approach, like

```
%if &varnobs ne 0 %then %do;
 data table2;
 *do your second dataset operation inside the macro only when varnobs is not 0...;
 run;
%end;
```

or putting your whole code into the macro...

I hope this code is basic enough for you, at the moment i cant think of a solution without using macro-variables...

Comment: Hi Thank you for your responses. I have tried adding the above to my code, which is below but I have something wrong.                           %macro check_data (table=qldreps);
data_null_; call symput ('varnobs',n_obs); stop;set &qldreps nobs=n_obs; run; %if &varnobs = 0 %then %do; ENDSAS; %end;%mend check_data; %check_data ("qldreps"); 
 PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE qldreps AS SELECT c.incident_number,    
 c.incident_type FROM 1 AS c, 2 as a  WHERE c.zone = a.zone
QUIT;
proc sql; CREATE TABLE detail AS SELECT a.incident_number FROM 1 as a,3 as b  WHERE a.incident_number = b.incident_number;QUIT;

Comment: @malibu2012 hm, one mistake i see is ´set &qldreps`  . You must use `set &table` , table is the variable you reference here, qldreps just a table name. If the tablename is always the same, you can remove (table=qldreps) in macrodefinition and call and just write `set qldreps`inside the macro. But it is difficult to analyse your code here, because of the formatting in the comment.Also your macro call `%check_data ("qldreps"); `must be after creating the table, so place it after the proc sql

Comment: Best for testing would be, just copy my code in answer at it is, and then insert your proc sql for table creation between %mend check_data; and
%check_data("qldreps ");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kl78

I have copied the code you supplied as is and now I get an error saying "more positional parameters found the defined"

I have my code as follows

%macro check_data(table=qldreps);

data *null*;

```
call symput('varnobs',n_obs);

stop;

set &table nobs=n_obs;
```

run;

%if &varnobs = 0 %then %do;

```
ENDSAS;
```

%end;

%mend check_data;

proc sql;

create table qldreps as

select c.incident_num,

```
   c.incident_type
```

from cad.incindet as c

where c.incident_type =601;

quit;

%check_data("qldreps");

proc sql;

create table detail as

select b.details

from qldreps as a,

```
cad.incident_detail as b
```

where a.incident_number=b.incident_number;

quit;

what I am not getting? thank you

Comment: If you define a parameter as named (with an equal sign) you cannot turn around and call it as if you had defined it as positional. The easiest change is to add the parameter name in the macro call.  `%check_data(table=qldreps)`.  Also do not include the quotes around the parameter value.  In this case it will cause SAS to look for a file named "qldreps.sas7bdat" in the current directory instead of using the dataset work.qldreps.